# Orthogonal complement of a subspace in a Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

In [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/53330/double-orthogonal-complement) it is stated that  if $W$ is a closed subspace of $V$, we may define $W^\perp$ to be the subspace of all vectors $v \in V$ such that $\langle v | w\rangle =0$ for all $w \in  W$.

Does the subspace really have to be closed to define the orthogonal complement? I believe it's possible to define the orthogonal complement of any subset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're absolutely right. You can just as easily define $S^\bot$ for any subset $S$ of your Hilbert space $V$.

$$S^\bot = \{ v \in V : \langle v \vert w \rangle = 0 \text{ for all } w \in S \}$$

You can also check that, no matter the structure of $S$,

- $S^\bot$ is a closed subspace, and
- $(S^\bot)^\bot$ is the smallest closed subspace containing $S$.

Comment: But then why is an operator $u\in B(H)$ Fredholm if and only if $\mathrm{im}(u)$ is closed and $\ker u$ and $\ker u^\ast$ are finite dimensional? Isn't it enough to have both kernels finite dimensional?

Comment: Guessing slightly at the source of confusion here, but: note that while, on the one hand, $\mathrm{ran}(u)^\bot = \ker(u^*)$,  going in the other direction you only have $\ker(u^*)^\bot = \overline{\mathrm{ran}(u)}$, the closure of the range.  If the range of $u$ happens to be closed, then $\ker(u^*) = \mathrm{ran}(u)$. What you want is for the $\mathrm{ran}(u)$ to be a closed subspace with a finite dimensional complement... does this help?

Comment: For an example where this distinction matters, consider the operator $T : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ which sends a sequence $(x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ to $(n x_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. Since, $\ker(T) = \{0\}$, the kernel is finite-dimensional. On the other hand, the range $T$ is dense since it contains the standard orthonormal basis for $\ell^2$. In spite of this, the operator is not Fredholm, there is not a finite dimensional complement for the range. Note, in this example, that $\ker(T^*) = \mathrm{ran}(T)^\bot = \{0\}$ is also finite-dimensional.

Comment: Typo in my first comment: should say "If the range of $u$ happens to be closed, then $\ker(u^*)^\bot = \mathrm{ran}(u)$."

Comment: Thank you for your help. How do I see that $(\ker u^\ast)^\bot =\overline{\mathrm{ran} u}$? It's very counter intuitive to me because $(\mathrm{ran}  u)^\bot = \ker u^\ast$. And for me this suggests that (by symmetry) we should have $(\ker u^\ast)^\bot =\mathrm{ran}  u$.

Comment: It's better if I make a new question about this. Thank you for your help!